# how to compress image in ionic 2

Tags: ionic2

I am actually implementing a function to allow user to upload the photos from phone. 
Is there any image compress plugin / library to recommended? 
Notes: it is image compression, not image resizing.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

[Use the Ionic Native Camera function](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/camera/)

There is a quality option ranging from 0-100. It will return a compressed image

```js
const options: CameraOptions = {
  quality: 50, // Try changing this 
  destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
  encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
  mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE
}

this.camera.getPicture(options).then((imageData) => {
 let base64Image = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageData;
}, (err) => {
 // Handle error
});
```

Comment: for me it seems like ionic is ignoring whatever quality I pass it...did this work for you?

Answer (score 1):

Try following CameraOptions with ionic camera plugin.

```
const options: CameraOptions = {
        quality: 20,
        targetWidth: 600, 
        targetHeight: 600,
        destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
        encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.PNG,
        mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
        sourceType: this.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
        allowEdit: true //may not work with some deices
}
```

It is targetHeight and targetWidth doing the magic. :)

Answer referred from : [Ionic image compress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45266483/ionic-3-compress-image)