# Ionic 3 compress image

Tags: javascript, image, typescript, ionic-framework, compression

I've been trying to compress an image client-side with Ionic 3 for 2 days now. I have tried:

`ng2-img-max` - throws an error when using the `blue-imp-canvas-to-blob` `canvas.toBlob()` method (a dependency of `ng2-img-max`). It was only telling me what line the error was happening on. I think I have read that creating an `HTMLCanvasElement` in Ionic isn't possible - something to do with `webworkers`.

`Ahdin - JS library
JIC - JS library
TinyJPG - npm module`

These all threw various errors, after researching them I determined its because the libraries/modules were not compatible with Ionic 3. I think a lot of the time it was a problem with the `HTMLCanvasElement`.

I tried the suggestion in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43760112/how-to-compress-image-in-ionic-2) question - but changing the `quality` variable isn't changing the size of the image.

Has anyone had success compressing images client-side using Ionic 3? How did you do it?

Comment: Did solution work for you?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try following `CameraOptions` with [camera plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/camera/).

```
const options: CameraOptions = {
        quality: 20,
        targetWidth: 600,
        targetHeight: 600,
        destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
        encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.PNG,
        mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
        sourceType: this.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
        allowEdit: true //may not work with some deices
}
```

Comment: thanks...does it need to be a png for compression to work? or is it the targetwidth/height?

Comment: I have the same question, how/why does this exactly work ?

Comment: it is targetHeight and targetWidth

Comment: this can be used only for native camera plugin, if you are using camera-preview-plugin there isn't any 'allowEdit' option in the options object.

Answer (score 2):

I am using [ngx-image-compress](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-image-compress)

```
import { NgxImageCompressService } from "ngx-image-compress";

constructor(public imageCompress: NgxImageCompressService) { }

private compressImage() {
      this.imageCompress.compressFile(data, '', 50, 50).then(result => {
         this.imageData = result;
      })
}
```

Play with the options, or loop the compressing process to get the desired result :)